# How to name a volume using a docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, modx

I'm new to Docker and I'm trying to find out how to set the name of the created data volume. Currently the directory is automatically named as a long hash under /var/libs/docker which is far from user friendly.

I'm attempting to set up a development environment for MODX as shown here:
https://github.com/modxcms/docker-modx

Currently my docker-compose.yml file is as follows:

```
web:
  image: modx
  links:
    - db:mysql
  ports:
    - 80:80
db:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  command: mysqld --sql-mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
myadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  links:
    - db:db
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
```

This works perfectly but I'm unsure as to how to name the data volume that I would edit directly with my IDE.

(As a side question, does it have to be created under /var/libs/docker ? Or is there a way of setting it to a directory in my home folder?)

**Update:**
Thanks to the help from @juliano I've updated my docker-compose.yml file to:

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
      image: modx
      volumes: 
        - html:/home/muzzstick/dev/modxdev
      links:
        - db:mysql
      ports:
        - 80:80
    db:
      image: mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      ports:
        - 3306:3306
      command: mysqld --sql-mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
    myadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      links:
        - db:db
      ports:
        - 8080:8080

volumes:
    html:
        external: false
```

Unfortunately this seems to stop the web container from running. 
db and myadmin containers show they're running ok.
There weren't any errors... if I type `docker start docker_web_1` it appears to start but `docker ps -a` shows it exited as soon as it started.

**Update 2**

Running `docker-compose up -d` appears to run without issue. But then as you can see below, the web container exits as soon as it's created.

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                            NAMES
a1dd6d8ac94e        modx                    "/entrypoint.sh apach"   10 seconds ago      Exited (1) 5 seconds ago                                    docker_web_1
ee812ae858dc        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/run.sh phpmyadmin"     10 seconds ago      Up 5 seconds               80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   docker_myadmin_1
db496134e0cf        mysql                   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   11 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds              0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp           docker_db_1
```

**Update 3**
OK the error logs for this container shows:

```
error: missing MODX_DB_HOST and MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP environment variables
Did you forget to --link some_mysql_container:mysql or set an external db
with -e MODX_DB_HOST=hostname:port?
```

This error appears to be originating from https://github.com/modxcms/docker-modx/blob/master/apache/docker-entrypoint.sh#L15-L20

Could it be something like linking is handled differently in docker-compose version 2?

Comment: What happens when you run `docker-compose up`?

Comment: It pulls the various images as expected and creates the containers. But the web container exits almost immediately as you can see in my update above.

Answer (score 12):

To create a named data volume using the [version 2 of compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/version-2) you will have a separated area:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - amazingvolume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  amazingvolume:
    external: true
```

So you can define the volume name (amazingvolume), if it's [external or not](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external) and under your service (db in this example) you can define which directory you gonna mount.

Comment: if we go this way, we cannot edit files within the volume directory (which would be mounted to a physical file location). This would not be a good case for developers who need to test / develop files locally, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just search in the docker documentation for hosted mounted volumes:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: modx
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP=3306
      - MODX_DB_HOST=mysql:3306
    volumes: 
      - /home/muzzstick/dev/modxdev/html:/var/www/html

    links:
      - db:mysql
    ports:
      - 80:80
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    command: mysqld --sql-mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
  myadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - db:db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Change `/var/www/html` to the directory where the html files will be inside the container. And also create the directory at the left in your host and give read permission to all users.

Regards

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I tried this too but it has the same problem as shown in my updated question above unfortunately. The web container exits immediately.

Comment: And what it says in the logs? docker logs containername

Comment: Add this environment variable to docker-compose.yml MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP=3306 it is what I see in the script. I see errors in this script. You are doing what they suggest in the Readme so I recommend you write them

Comment: Also I recommend adding MODX_DB_HOST=mysql:3306 because I don't see how they will get the port using just the link option.